# Is there locking in the Atomic compareAndSet method in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, atomic

If I have something like:

```
AtomicReference<String> atomicReference = new AtomicReference<>("abc");
```

I have 2 threads executing code:

**Thread 1:** `atomicReference.compareAndSet("abc", "def")`

**Thread 2:** `atomicReference.compareAndSet("abc", "efg")`

Could there be a case where both threads exceute this at same time and find the value "abc" which was declared and both executes the method
or if one thread exceutes compareandset other will have to wait until it completes (basically some kind of locking mechanism)?

Comment: "Could there be a case where both threads exceute this at same time" no.

Comment: @AndyTurner Well they can happily execute at the same time, but there can only be one winner.

Comment: @AndyTurner is right, but it's consumer responsibility to check the return value of .compareAndSet (whether operation succeeded or not and repeat if it didn't).

Answer (score 1):

In general, reasonable implementation will not use a lock for atomic `compareAndSet`. Some old/very low-end 32-bit architectures may use a lock for `AtomicLong`.

The method bodies may (some architectures) allow execution by more than one thread at a time, but only one can succeed.

Comment: okay so basically even if it happens, some way JVM detects it and will give false for one of the compareAndSet, right?

But once the thread goes inside compareAndSet, why would it fail, because at intial check i.e. both threads matched the expected value, so where is this next validation happening?

Comment: @punter316 It's a hardware thing. IIRC, the 486 introduced CMPXCHG - a 32-bit CAS in one instruction. I believe later efforts allow more flexibility with multiple load/stores acting transitionally. The point is that it is usually somewhat faster than locking and avoids the threads blocking.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it can happen that both threads execute at the same time. But there is always just one "winner", just one will succeed.

Answer (score -1):

From the documentation:

> **Package java.util.concurrent.atomic**
>
> A small toolkit of classes that support lock-free thread-safe programming on single variables.